# Empty Documents folder

Tags: home-directory, data-loss

My `home/user/Documents` folder has become empty. Permissions have also been changed and trying to write to it is not permitted. I assume it happened after an upgrade to the new Kernel 45. 
I noticed a strangely named (temporary?) file "tmpmGRH...lots of random letters ...Lqa", 17GB in size which I assume contains the data.
I have a not so recent backup but unfortunately not at my location.
Any ideas on what happened and how to recover the data and/or restore the folder would be greatly appreciated.

`ls -la | head -5`

```
total 8
dr-xr-xr-t  2 user user 4096 okt 24 21:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 59 user user 4096 okt 27 15:33 ..
```

Comment: Will you show the output of `ls -la $HOME/Documents | head -5`?

Comment: thanks for taking the time. Here's what that got me: `total 8` //
`dr-xr-xr-t  2 user user 4096 okt 24 21:36 .` //
`drwxr-xr-x 59 user user 4096 okt 27 09:04 ..` By the way is there a tutorial on the formatting here on the forum.

Comment: Yes.   For formatting help, click on the `?` in the `Menu` header of where you type questions or answers.  To get more help  click the `advance help` othat shows whn you click on `?`.  For help with the commands click `help`.  The formatting options in the comments are very limited.

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with the output of what the comment session is showing.   I can't identify with the `//` that is showing.  Will you edit your question and paste the output of the command to your question.  You can format the output by selecting what you past, then click on the `{}` icon at the top of the Question's editor.

Comment: @ L.D. James well it seems some addon/setting of my firefox was messing with the comment editor. I didn't get to see any of the formatting options. the // was supposed to indicate a line break. I have posted the output in the question section

Comment: The sticky bit appears to be set. who are you logged in as? check the output of `whoami` against the owner of the user directory

Comment: @ElderGeek The `$HOME` variable should be showing the same as the `whoami` command.  I previously used that as the identifier, but received and edit and a downvote to my answer that `whoami` isn't reliable and a suggestion to the `$USER` variable.

Comment: @ElderGeek checked in as the user. Using sudo gives the same output. Is there any knowledge on how a folder -> file conversion could take place. I have found a few comments about similar folder <-> file conversion problems but no definite answers.

Comment: Based on the output of `ls -la $HOME/Documents` try `chmod -t home/user/Documents`

Comment: @Elder Geek that hasn't changed anything in the output

Comment: @chris did you receive an error when you ran the command?

Comment: @Elder Geek no nothing just returned to the command line. I considered changing the permission to make the folder usable again but was not sure if this would create some write command on that partition. After a bit of reading on what might cause this problem, it came up as a big no-no in case of data-loss. I guess on a boot up/shut down the system detected no Documents folder and created a new one with less rights. I don't know what linux does if an essential folder in the home directory goes missing. The underlying problem of folder->file conversion is still something that puzzles me.

Comment: Based on your comments on L.D.James answer (among the others) I would place my bets on a  failing drive or stuck bit in RAM as being the root cause. One bit being zero rather than a 1 (or vice versa) can have a giant impact.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to your `Documents` folder because you have the `w` bit turned off, and the `t` (sticky bit) turned on.  You can fix your `Documents` directory back to the default with:

```
$ chmod 0755 ~/Documents
```

As far as your previous files you'll have to try to recall the names of some of the files that you are sure were previously in your `Documents` folder and locate one.  When you find the one, the others should be in the same folder.

You can do this with:

```
$ locate -ir "locate -ir "Intel.*pdf"
/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases.pdf
/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases2.pdf
/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases3.pdf
/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases4.pdf
/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases5.pdf
/mnt2/datadrive/extroot/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases.pdf
/mnt2/datadrive/extroot/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases2.pdf
/mnt2/datadrive/extroot/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases3.pdf
/mnt2/datadrive/extroot/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases4.pdf
/mnt2/datadrive/extroot/home/users/l/j/ljames/Documents/IntelliApp Releases5.pdf
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Browser/intellinux/nppdf.so
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/AcroForm/adobepdf.xdc
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/AcroForm/PMP/libpdf417pmp.pmp
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/Annotations/Stamps/Words.pdf
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/Annotations/Stamps/ENU/Dynamic.pdf
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/Annotations/Stamps/ENU/SignHere.pdf
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/Annotations/Stamps/ENU/StandardBusiness.pdf
```

The above example is a `regex` search using `locate`.  In the above example I know I saved an "Intelli" document as a `.pdf` file.  So locating that document will show the directory where I could look for other documents in the same area.

The `$` is the command prompt, with the command following the prompt.  The text after the commandline is the output of the command.

Comment: changing the permission helped writing again into the folder. However I could discover no files/folders using locate or find. My feeling is that somehow a bit/serveral bits changed which caused the change into this giant file. Strangly it is dated to 01-04-16, so way back. Neither fsck nor Testdisk yielded any sign of problems. Photorec found a bunch of stuff (ca 18000 files totaling 17GB) and a quick look shows me some valid files. I have no idea what excactly caused this transformation or when exactly it happend but speculate it was during/after the Kernal update.

Comment: The purpose of the `locate` command was to actual determine if were the files are if they still exist.  I'm glad you are able to write to your `~/Documents` folder and the bit change worked.  Whatever caused the `w` flag of your `~/Documents` folder might have also affected the `read` flag of the folder the original Documents folder.  Try using `sudo` with the `locate` command.  By the way the `locate` command should be faster.  It'll use the index that is created daily of all the files on your attached drives.

Comment: Tried it with sudo already but again nothing was found. I just mentioned above, I considered changing the rights before but was not sure if this would create a write command for this partition. I was using a bunch of tools via a USB booted system to check for errors in the partition table and harddrive internals but again nothing wrong came up (at least as far as I could tell). This newly created very large file also seems to be rather unaccessible to various editors, compression, database programs,...